# Issue using New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment in place of New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a graph API role in PowerShell and getting the following generic error when using graph instead of AzureAD module.

Error:

"One or more errors occurred"

InnerException: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

The service principal I am connecting with has the following **delegated** permissions with admin consent:

- Application.ReadWrite.All
- AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All
- DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All

Code:

```
$ApplicationId = '<Myappid>'
$SecuredPassword = '<MyAppID secret>'
$tenantID = '<MyTenantID>'

$SecuredPasswordPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $SecuredPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecuredPasswordPassword

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $tenantID -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential 

$params = @{
    "PrincipalId" = "<principalID>"  #ObjectID of the enterprise app for my app registration
    "ResourceId" = "resourceID" #ID of graph service principal ID in my tenant
    "AppRoleId" = "approleID" #ID of the graph role
}

  try {
    New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId "<same as resource ID in params; Graph api id>" -BodyParameter $params -ErrorAction:Stop
  }
  catch {
    $tmpError = $_.exception
  }
```

Comment: What version of the PowerShell module are you using? (check with `Get-Command New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment`). Can you share the exception details when you run the cmdlet with `-Debug` (i.e. `New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -Debug -ServicePrincipalId ...`)?

Comment: Module version: 2.1.0.  Debug:  mdletException]: Received exception with message 'AggregateException - One or more errors occurred. :    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.EventFactory.CreateLogEvent(Task`1 message)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment_Create.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.IEventListener.Signal>b__1()

Comment: Using Application scope does allow this to work, but generates the same error exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an Azure AD Application and granted **`AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All`** **Application permission**:

[image]

To **assign Graph role to the Service Principal**, make use of below PowerShell script:

```
$ApplicationId = "AppID"
$tenantID = "TenantID"

Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $ApplicationId -TenantId $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxx"

$params = @{
principalId = "ServicePrincipalObjectID"
resourceId = "MicrosoftGraphObjectID"
appRoleId = "5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b"
}

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalObjectID -BodyParameter $params
```

[image]

The **`Group.Read.All`** API permission got assigned successfully to the Service Principal like below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check whether you are passing valid `resourceId`:

The Application ID with ID `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`

[image]

- In your case, you are passing `ServicePrincipalId` as Graph App ID which is invalid, you have to pass the same ID as `principalId`.

```
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalObjectID -BodyParameter $params
```

- Assign **Application API permission** to perform the action as you are connecting to `MgGraph` in the Application context.

**Reference:**

[Grant an appRoleAssignment to a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#request)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply Rukmini, and it does work. I am trying to test this with delegated permission though. I have been testing for scenarios when apps have the ability to elevate their permissions.